# Model Not Found in Ember App Kit

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-app-kit

I'm trying to use Ember App Kit with Ember Data (I'm using the latest of Both) using Fixtures - but for some reason I'm getting the following:

`Assertion failed: No model was found for 'todo' [VM] ember.js (4005):415`

`Error while loading route: TypeError {} [VM] ember.js (4005):415`

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'store' of undefined ember-data.js:2182`

**Application**

```
import Resolver from 'resolver';
import registerComponents from 'appkit/utils/register_components';

var App = Ember.Application.extend({
  LOG_ACTIVE_GENERATION: true,
  LOG_MODULE_RESOLVER: true,
  LOG_TRANSITIONS: true,
  LOG_TRANSITIONS_INTERNAL: true,
  LOG_VIEW_LOOKUPS: true,
  modulePrefix: 'appkit', // TODO: loaded via config
  Resolver: Resolver
});

App.initializer({
  name: 'Register Components',
  initialize: function(container, application) {
    registerComponents(container);
  }
});

App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.FixtureAdapter.extend();

export default App;
```

**Index Route**

```
import Todo from 'appkit/models/Todo';

var IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.findAll('todo');
  }
});

export default IndexRoute;
```

**Todo Model**

```
var Todo = DS.Model.extend({
  'title': DS.attr('string'),
  'user': DS.attr('object'),
  'comment': DS.attr('string'),
  'mood': DS.attr('string')
});

Todo.FIXTURES = [{ 
    'title': 'Received Hardware!', 
    'user': { 'username': 'alvincrespo' }, 
    'comment': 'Finally received my hardware!',
    'mood': 'happy'
}, {
    'title': 'This is honorable.', 
    'user': { 'username': 'robwolf' }, 
    'comment': 'I regret it already.',
    'mood': 'happy'
}, {
    'title': 'I can\'t seem to speak', 
    'user': { 'username': 'catstark' }, 
    'comment': 'Wait a minute, why am I hear?',
    'mood': 'sad'
}, {
    'title': 'Attendance is poor.', 
    'user': { 'username': 'cerlan' }, 
    'comment': 'Kings landing seems pretty empty after the war.',
    'mood': 'neutral'
}];

export default Todo;
```

I've declared the `DS.FixtureAdapter` in `app.js` but for some reason its still not working? Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you fix your issue? I Have the same !

Answer (score 0):

I'm not positive about what the register components pieces does.  But essentially it's saying it doesn't know about the Todo Model (generally it find it by looking for model's described in its namespace, aka App.Todo = DS.Model.extend....)

You might also need to still declare the store.

```
 App.Store = DS.Store.extend();
```

And in Ember Data 1.0 beta 1 you do the adapter like so

```
 App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.MyRESTAdapter; // note you don't extend/create it
```

Comment: I did try to make it under the App namespace - but for some reason I still get the same issue :(

Comment: I think the example where it shows how to declare the default app adapter makes it seem like you don't need to declare the store, but I believe that is still required.

Comment: Hmm. Interesting. I've got the same discussion going on here: http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/model-not-found-ember-app-kit/2888 but from the Transition.md on github it seems that we shouldn't have to declare the store again :/